# how to receive broadcastrecevier, when device's date automatically change?

Tags: android

I am using `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED` in my Broadcast Receiver, and `android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED`
in `<receiver>...</receiver>` in my manifest file. I got result, when will user set device's date  manually using application->Date & Time setting->set date. But I don't want it, I want to receive, when device will change date automatically ie depending upon device's  time.is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` and set yourself a recurring alarm that goes off at midnight.